# Which one should I use between if (data!=null) and data?.let in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is common usage in java.

I havn't understanded completely the key let of Kotin. Which one should I use between Code A and Code B in kotlin? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
if (data!=null){
    initAndBindAdapter()
    mCustomAdapter.setSelectedIndex(data.getIntExtra("index",-1))
}
```

**Code B**

```
 data?.let {
    initAndBindAdapter()
    mCustomAdapter.setSelectedIndex(it.getIntExtra("index",-1))
 }
```

And more, which one should I choose between Code C and Code D in kotlin if the fun do_NoNeed_data_par doesn't need data parameter ?

**Code C**

```
   if (data!=null){
        do_NoNeed_data_par()        
    }
```

**Code D**

```
   data?.let {
       do_NoNeed_data_par()    
    }
```

Comment: There's no need to be fancy if the simple solution works just as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I (personal opinion) think it's a good idea to use simple, regular null checks where you can, although the `?.let` method has been listed under the main Kotlin [Idioms](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#execute-if-not-null) page of the documentation (which is open for the community to contribute) - so basically, this will be up to your personal preferences of which one is more readable.

The more interesting question is what are the differences, and when you can use each: the main difference is that `let` holds on to the value of the variable as it was when the `let` call on it started, and any subsequent uses of `it` within the `let` block will reference that same value. If you use a simple null check with `if`, your variable's value might be changed while the body of the `if` block is being executed.

So for example, this won't compile, because `x` can be accessed by multiple threads, and it might be non-null when you read its value first for the null check, but it might become null by the time you read it again for the `println` parameter - this would be unsafe:

```
class Foo {
    var x: Int? = null

    fun useX() {
        if (x != null) {
            println(x + 10) // (...) 'x' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time
        }
    }
}
```

However, a `let` will work in the same situation, because it will use whatever the initial value of `x` had all throughout its execution, even if the `x` property in the class gets reassigned in the meantime:

```
class Foo {
    var x: Int? = null

    fun useX() {
        x?.let {
            println(it + 10)
        }
    }
}
```

You can think of the `?.let` statement above of basically performing this, creating a temporary copy of your variable:

```
fun useX() {
    val _x = x
    if (_x != null) {
        println(_x + 10)
    }
}
```

Operating on this copy is safe, because even if the `x` property changes its value, this `_x` copy will either stay null for this entire function, or it's non-null and safe to use.

Comment: Thanks. Based your  explain, I should always use .`let` because it's  thread safe,right?

Comment: You still don't have to always use it - if you prefer regular null checks, the compiler will warn you when it's not thread/null safe.

Answer (score 1):

*"should"* is opinionated. It all depends on your preference.

If you prefer more functional style code then `.let` is your answer. If you prefer more procedural code then `== null` is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, using `let()` can be a concise alternative for `if`. But you have to use it with sound judgment in order to avoid unreadable “train wrecks”. Nevertheless, I really want you to consider using `let()`.

```
val order: Order? = findOrder()
if (order != null){
dun(order.customer)
}
```

With `let()`, there is no need for an extra variable. So we get along with one expression.

```
findOrder()?.let { dun(it.customer) }
```