# Kotlin let versus != null

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

What is the difference between using kotlin's `object?.let {...}` versus `if(object != null) {...}`? I've run into the situation where using `let` on a non-null equates to false and the block is not executed but using the `if` statement with the same object results in properly identifying that the object non-null and the block is executed.

Do they differ on the low level somehow?

Comment: would you be able to provide the code for the situation where this occured?

Comment: This should not be possible. If you can reproduce it, please post code. If the question is only about the difference between the two, they're discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51094692/4465208

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which one should I use between if (data!=null) and data?.let in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093601/which-one-should-i-use-between-if-data-null-and-data-let-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, `object?.let { }` will be compiled to `if (object != null) { }`. You can try to check the kotlin bytecode.

IMHO, using `let` also may benefit you to chaining function which makes your code declarative, and I think it is more readable.

Answer (score -2):

One of the scenario where `let` keyword is preferable when you are reading the list of items that also contains null values and you wants to print only not-null values.
For Example:-

```
var array = arrayOf("StackOverflow", "Kotlin", "Android", null, "Jetpack", null)
for (item in array) {
    item?.let {
        print("$it ")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
StackOverflow Kotlin Android Jetpack
```

Code inside for loop is like saying "if item is not null, let's print its value". Therefore `?.let` allows you to run code for a value that's not null.

Comment: Why would it necessarily be preferable than an if statement in this case?

Comment: In case of `if`, there is no guarantee that `item` variable won't change in between the null-check and its usage.  `let` keyword mostly used in conjunction with the safe call operator `?.` tells the
compiler that you want to perform some action when the value it’s
operating on is not null.

Comment: Exactly, so the real reason that they're different is because you're capturing its value as `it`, but you haven't mentioned that in your answer? You've only explained how they're the same.